# UISearchBar doesn't respond to touch event

Tags: iphone, delegates, mkmapview, uisearchbar

I am designing an IPhone app using MKMapView and UISearchBar, my issue is i need to make the keypad disappear when i touch the MapView or if i click the cancel button.

I tried using the codes:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];

}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
     [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

But both dint help.

Here is the ScreenShot:

[image]

So please someone help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                           initWithTarget:self
                                           action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

In dismissKeyboard:

```
 -(void)dismissKeyboard {
           [SearchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

(Where searchBar is the  that is responsible for the keyboard)

Comment: Ya it works. Thanks. But there my problem is not solved :( If i tap the cancel button keypad is getting disappeared Fine :-)  Also i need the keyPad to get disappeared when i touch the mapView and if i press the search button. Please see my ScreenShot uploaded above. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah i got it. Hold on .

Comment: Try this, - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBarr
{
    [searchBarr resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: Yeah it helped solving the other issue thanks. Now the only issue is The keyPad needs to disappear when i touch the mapView. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updated one that doesn't use Xib file:

.h file:

[image]

.m file:

[image]

Hope this gives you an insight.

Comment: thank you, But i am not using userInterface(XIB). Even then should i add IBOutlet?

Comment: And also i need the keyPad to get disappeared when i touch the mapView and if i press the search button. Please see my ScreenShot uploaded above. Thanks.

Comment: Did you just code in (without Xib) to create your map and search bar?

Comment: yeah ! in my company i am not supposed to use Xib. Hence i had coded everything Programatically.

Comment: Okay. I have updated the answer. You will get an idea. And again, in order to dismiss the keyboard when search button pressed, you have a delegate method that lets you dismiss the KB

Comment: Yeah @geni it works but what about the other two conditions? **"And also i need the keyPad to get disappeared when i touch the mapView and if i press the search button. Please see my ScreenShot uploaded above. Thanks."**

Comment: I solved the issue to get disappear the keyPad when i click search. Now the only issue is The keyPad needs to disappear when i touch the mapView. Thanks.